# limit of sequences $c_n=(-2)^n$ and $d_n=\frac{n^3+1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to find the limits of the following sequences using definition of convergence

$$a_n=\frac 1 n \quad \quad b_n=n^2 \quad \quad c_n=(-2)^n \quad \quad d_n=\frac{n^3+1}{n^2}$$

$a_n,b_n$ were no problem for me:

$$\epsilon \geq |a_n-a|=\left|\frac 1 n - 0\right|=\left|\frac 1 n\right|=\frac 1 n$$
so we get $n \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ We set $N:=\left\lceil \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right\rceil$ and we're done.

but I'm struggling with $c_n$ and $d_n$. I know from Wolfram Aplha, that $d_n$ converge. Perhaps someone can give me a hint?

Comment: "I know from Wolfram Alpha that $c_n=0$ and $d_n=\infty$" What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28-2%29%5En ; I entered the sequence there

Comment: Yeah, and you failed to read correctly WA's answer (which, in any case, does not say that $c_n=0$ or that $d_n=\infty$, fortunately for WA since $c_n=(-2)^n$, not $0$, and $d_n=(n^3+1)/n^2$, not $\infty$...).

Comment: Ah thanks for your hint; I deleted the sentence in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $c_n$ doesn't converge (the elements of the sequence are $-2, 4, -8, 16, \ldots$ so it has two different extended partial limits - $+\infty$ and $-\infty$).

For $d_n$, if you want to show that $d_n \to \infty$, you need to show that for each $M$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$ you have

$$ d_n = \frac{n^3 + 1}{n^2} = n + \frac{1}{n^2} > M. $$

If you will take $N = M$, then since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is always positive you will have

$$ d_n = n + \frac{1}{n^2} > n > N = M $$

for all $n > N$, as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For $c_n$ I don't have to show, that there is no convergence?

Comment: You probably do, and I'll leave it to you to prove it rigorously.